# Confusion in perl print behaviour

Tags: perl, printing

I am confused with the behaviour of 'print' function.  The below one is my code :-

```
$var1 = "VARIBLE";
@arr = ();
push (@arr,$var1);
```

And when I add print function to the above code,

```
print @arr;
```

It gives 'VARIBLE' as output.  But When I replace the above line with the below line,

```
print @arr."\n";
```

It gives out '1' as output.  Could someone tell me what is actually going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because you are *concatenating* `@arr` with `\n`. This essentially says that you want to treat `@arr` as a scalar so that it can be concatenated to another scalar, which is `1` in this case because there is one element in the array. See [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Context) for more information about how context affects the interpretation of a variable.

What you probably want is:

```
print @arr, "\n";
```

Answer (score 4):

An array in scalar context gives the number of elements in the array:

```
print scalar @arr; #result is one for your array.
```

Scalar context can be specified explicitly with the `scalar` keyword, as shown in the example.  However, scalar context also occurs whenever an operation naturally requires a single value.  For example:

```
#A numeric comparison requires a single value, so this is scalar context.
if (@arr > 0) { print "array has elements" }
```

String concatenation is an operation that naturally requires a single value on each side of the `.`,  thus it creates scalar context and you get the size of the array.

The simplest solution in your case is to use a comma instead:

```
print @arr,"\n";
```

`print` accepts a list of arguments and prints them all, which is why `print @arr` works in the first place.  By adding another term with a comma, you are just adding one more thing to the list of arguments that will be printed.

Comment: You might want to mention that this can be solved through precedence control: `print ( @arr . "\n" );`

Comment: @Zaid, the parentheses don't make a difference, because concatenation forces scalar context regardless. And concatenation has higher precedence anyway.

Comment: I must be tired today... didn't realize it was an array and not a scalar.

Comment: @dan1111.  Thank you very much for your help.  Now I got a clear idea about 'scalar' and '.'.

Answer (score 1):

As previous answers say, it's different because of the context: scalar vs array.
Also, there is a third sentence that may be interesting for you:

```
my @array = qw(one two three);
print "@array", "\n";  #<-- observe the "" quotes;
#prints: one two three

print @array, "\n";  #<-- without quotes;
#prints: onetwothree
```

This is because string interpolation of variables inside doble quotation marks. The array interpolation separates the items by the content of special perl variable `$"` (by default, the content of this variable is a blank space). If there isn't interpolation, perl will print the contents of the array without any separator.

`$"` allows you to change the way to interpolate strings in print; example:

```
{
   local $" = '-';
   print "@array", "\n";
   #prints: one-two-three
}
```

Comment: Useful information, but if you are going to do string interpolation, you should really do `print "@array\n";`.

Comment: @dan1111 I don't see your point, "\n" doesn't matters (inside or outside the string) in my answer

Comment: Sure, your code works--but the main benefit of string interpolation is that you can use one string.  You don't need to cobble multiple strings together.  I just think your answer would be improved if it illustrated that.